# How to addHeadher in Rest Assured when the list is already given but for few API's it changes

Tags: api, automation, bdd, rest-assured, cucumber-java

```
RequestSpecBuilder RS = new RequestSpecBuilder()
                .setBaseUri(GetURL("StgURL"))
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("x-device-id", "kjbwejfbwkjefclw")
                .addHeader("x-api-client", "abcjojnoenc")
                .addHeader("x-platform", "Android")
                .addHeader("x-country", "IN")
                .addHeader("x-api-token", UserValidation_StepDefination.Token)
                .addFilter(RequestLoggingFilter
                .logRequestTo(Log))
                .addFilter(ResponseLoggingFilter
                .logResponseTo(Log))
                .setContentType(ContentType.JSON);
```

In this case we have this set of header which is mandatory in all the API's but for other API's i have to add 1 or 2 Header More, not sure how i can achieve in Steps definition file

```
    @Given("payload")
    public void payload() throws IOException {
    rqsp = given().spec(requestSpecifications());   

    }
```

Comment: How are you going to differentiate between the API's in your feature file ?

Comment: I don't have to, just i am passing the same name which i have mentioned in API_resource  file using enum

Comment: I don't understand, Based on the code I see that you have a set of headers defined as a part of the requestSpec which you plan to use for all of the API's, but there's also a point where you say that for some specific API's you need extra headers to be configured. Adding a header is relatively easy `given().header("k","v")` but the question is how do you plan to differentiate which API's need the additional headers

Comment: In step definition i'll add the extra header in @given implementation and rest header will be called through RequestSpecification

Comment: Hi Kuldeep, This question has been open for a while and if you still haven't found a solution for this then I suggest you update the question a little further as to what exactly you are looking for / problem statement and we'd be happy to help further